# Error : Flow : activate Lighting runtime

Tags: visual-workflow, dependent-picklist, component

I have created a flow which contains a Dependent picklist component.

When I execute the flow I obtain this error (screen 306). However, I have activated the permission, so I don't understand where the problem is.
Can you help me?

> You have 2 warnings.
>   Just a heads up... (2)
>   These issues don't prevent activation, but can cause problems when you run the flow.
>   Completer_la_fiche_candidat (Screen) - This screen includes screen components that require Lightning runtime.
>   Completer_la_fiche_client (Screen) - This screen includes screen components that require Lightning runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not errors, just warnings. Basically, if you try to run flows outside of Lightning (e.g. in Classic), errors may prevent successful conclusion of the flow. The warnings are there so you know that you can have problems with the Flow if you try to run it as a standalone or inside Visualforce.